# binding controllers from other controllers not working in rc8

Tags: ember.js

In Ember rc6 I was successfully binding a controller `JobsTableColumnsController` to an attribute `columns` inside of a controller `JobsTableController`. The `JobsTableColumnsController` would be created and bound to the `columns` attribute automatically.

Here is the code that works in rc6:

```
App.JobsTableRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> App.Job.all()
  setupController: (ctlr, model) -> ctlr.set('content', model)

App.JobsTableController = App.TableController.extend  
  needs: ['jobsTableColumns']
  columnsBinding: 'controllers.jobsTableColumns'

App.JobsTableColumnsController = App.ColumnsController.extend
  content: Em.A([
    App.ColumnDefinition.create(name: 'Id')
    App.ColumnDefinition.create(name: 'Description')
  ])
```

In rc8 I have to explicitly set the `JobsTableColumnsController` to the `JobsTableController.columns` attribute in the router like so:

```
App.JobsTableRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> App.Job.all()
  setupController: (ctlr, model) -> 
    columns = @controllerFor('jobsTableColumns')
    ctlr.set('columns', columns)
    ctlr.set('content', model)
```

Is this a bug, or do I need to change my strategy of binding controllers to attributes using the `needs` attribute.

Comment: jsbin example with fix from @intuitivepixel http://jsbin.com/AFOFAHU/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a bug, or do I need to change my strategy of binding controllers to attributes using the needs attribute.

No it's not a bug, the use of `somePropertyBinding` was *quietly* deprecated in favor of computed properties. For reference please see the comment by Peter Wagenet here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1164#issuecomment-23200023

And as for the new strategy you should use `Ember.computed.alias`.

#### Example:

```
App.JobsTableController = App.TableController.extend  
  needs: ['jobsTableColumns']
  columns: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.jobsTableColumns')
```

This way you don't need the extra work in the `JobsTableRoute` `setupController` hook.

Hope it helps.